# Preventing a control changing its Text property while it is not enabled

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have some `DomainUpDown` controls in my application. The behaviour is set like this:

- Normal: Each control can individually goes Up/Down (Change selected item)
- Special: If a check box is checked, Up/Downing the first control will cause the other controls to change as well

Now there are some cases that I want some of the controls to be disabled by setting `Disabled = true`. I did it, but in this case changing the selected item of the first control will cause the other disabled controls to change the selected item as well.

Is there a way to completly disable a control so it does not accepts something like `control.Text = "bla bla"` ?

P.S: I need not to hide the control!

Comment: In the Event that updates the TextBox values why not simply check the Enabled property on the TextBox and only alter the text if it is set to true?

Comment: I reserved that as my last option. Since number of controls are a lot and requires a lot of editing. I was hoping that there is a way to completly disable a control and I wonder why `Disabled` does not really disables a contro!

Comment: Disabled simply prevents users from interacting with the control or raising Events.  MSDN:  With the Enabled property, you can enable or disable controls at run time. For example, you can disable controls that do not apply to the current state of the application. You can also disable a control to restrict its use. For example, a button can be disabled to prevent the user from clicking it. If a control is disabled, it cannot be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

You can hold a list of Textbox.Text values, which will hold entries for all of your textboxes.

Upon `OnTextChanged`:

- if your textbox is **enabled** - update it's `text` property and store it up in the list.
- if your textbox is **disabled** - set it's text `property` to the last value you had in your list.

You can use a `Dictionary` or anything similar that contain  `KeyValuePair` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's not. At least not without additional work.

Comment: Thats not an answer. I won't -1 you but you need to elaborate more... what's the 'additional work'?

Comment: @Shai Either you can derive your own TextBox (or component you're using) and check the `Disabled` property when modifying `Text` or handle it directly with standard one using `TextChanged` event.